# NSScroller won't auto-hide and spawns a new NSTableColumn for himself

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I can't figure out what's wrong with my `NSScrollers`.

Since an indefinite amount of time (I have been changing a lot of things in the source code of my App, but not on it's Xib design), my `NSScrollers` of all of my `TableViews` and `OutlineView` which are configured with "`AutoHides`" will not auto-hide at-all and will be spawned in a separate `NSTableColumn`.

I have no clue as where to look or how to debug this behavior, expect playing randomly with Interface Builder Settings for `NSScrollViews` .

I haven't made any weird categories that may interfere with the proper behavior of `tableViews`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I finally found a nice class that can do all I need by itself :[RFOverlayScrollView](https://github.com/rheinfabrik/RFOverlayScrollView/tree/master/RFOverlayScrollView). It's a nice subclass of NSScroller which is both transparent and auto-hidden; and published under the [MIT License](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103273/can-i-use-mit-licence-plugins-in-my-commercial-web-site).

## RFOverlayScrollView

> RFOverlayScrollView is an NSScrollView subclass that shows its NSScroller in iOS style even when a mouse is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found what you want, but have you tried setting

```
[_scrollView setScrollerStyle:NSScrollerStyleOverlay];
```

This however hijacks the scrollbar setting, even if **Show Scrollbars** settings in *System Preferences* is set to **Always**.

Comment: Truth be told, I tried a lot of stuff and setting scroller style to `NSScrollerScryleOverlay` was one of them (and didn't work as is). Overlay scrollers seem to be really recent and Apple Doc mentioned them without a lot of details. So I finally gave up.